# Android AppCompat change text color of material buttons

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I want to change button's text color, but I can't figure out how (I want to use buttons from AppCompat v22.2). I tried `android:color`, `android:textColor`, `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:colorForeground`, but these didn't do the job for me.

Can you say me what could go wrong or show a working example where you change text color of button to e.g. green? I'll be really happy when it'll be over :-)

*I looked for solution for about four days, so please don't reply with links to Google Search. If you have anything relevant, then please link that*

---

There was `android:style="?android/textAppearanceSmall"` in Button definition in layout XML (activity was generated from LoginActivity). I'm sorry for that (I actually don't know how to say it better in English).

Comment: the text color is based on your app theme's `colorAccent`

Comment: @tyczj Text color is still black (I "extended" Theme.AppCompat.Light) whether I set `accentColor` to white or black, so I suppose this doesn't work at all.
Ehm... sory for my English

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in your theme at you have your parent as `Theme.AppCompat.Light` you should have an item that reads `<item name="colorAccent">somecolor</item>` if you dont then you need to add it then set the color. This works perfectly fine for me

Comment: Thank you both, when I tried to create an MCVE, I found that something is broken in my Activity layout and then I found the style declaration.

Comment: BTW for me the text color of buttons depends on `android:textColor`, not on `accentColor`. I have `accentColor` set to green and `android:textColor` set to blue and the button has blue text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since I asked the question, but I didn't know how to properly close questions when I find the solution by myself back then, so I'm doing it now so that users who get here find their answer where they expect it to be.

The problem was that the Button's style was set to `?android/textAppearanceSmall` (wrong even if I wanted to use the attribute :) ), so it just fell back to default values for everything. Once I removed the `android:style` attribute, everything was OK.